# Incorrect legend labels in python seaborn plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

[image]

The above plot is made using seaborn in python. However, not sure why some of the legend circles are filled in with color and others are not. This is the colormap I am using:

```
sns.color_palette("Set2", 10)

g = sns.factorplot(x='month', y='vae_factor', hue='ad_name', col='crop', data=df_sub_panel,
                   col_wrap=3, size=5, lw=0.5, ci=None, capsize=.2, palette=sns.color_palette("Set2", 10),
                   sharex=False, aspect=.9, legend_out=False)
g.axes[0].legend(fancybox=None)
```

--EDIT:

Is there a way the circles can be filled? The reason they are not filled is that they might not have data in this particular plot

Comment: Perhaps the data is missing, since I don't see any data about Mexico, USA, Canada and Kazachstan. Can you should the `df_sub_panel` dataframe?

Comment: oh wow! really good point. Seaborn is smarter than me.

Comment: however, why is Kazakhstan color same as China? There are 10 colors in Set2

Comment: and is there  away to force the circles to be filled?

Comment: Can you report which seaborn and matplotlib version you are using? The reason for Kasachstan having the same color as China is that ["Set2" only has 8 colors](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_examples/color/colormaps_reference_04.pdf), so the ninth one will be repeated from the start.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I am using latest versions of both seaborn (0.8) and matpltolib (2.0)

Comment: What about test data?

Comment: If you seriously want an answer, provide a [mcve]. I.e. some example data with a code to run to reproduce this. When I'm plotting a factorplot with missing data, the legend does not have unfilled circles in it.

Comment: What's the point of having the absent variables in the legend? And, if you actually need them in the legend then isn't it a good distinction that they are not filled? They can be easily identified.

Comment: @user308827 This is impossible to reproduce without a working example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The circles are not filled in when there is no data, as I think you've already deduced.  But it can be forced by manipulating the legend object.

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df_sub_panel = pd.DataFrame([
  {'month':'jan', 'vae_factor':50, 'ad_name':'China', 'crop':False},
  {'month':'feb', 'vae_factor':60, 'ad_name':'China', 'crop':False},
  {'month':'feb', 'vae_factor':None, 'ad_name':'Mexico', 'crop':False},
])

sns.color_palette("Set2", 10)

g = sns.factorplot(x='month', y='vae_factor', hue='ad_name', col='crop', data=df_sub_panel,
                   col_wrap=3, size=5, lw=0.5, ci=None, capsize=.2, palette=sns.color_palette("Set2", 10),
                   sharex=False, aspect=.9, legend_out=False)

# fill in empty legend handles (handles are empty when vae_factor is NaN)
for handle in g.axes[0].get_legend_handles_labels()[0]:
  if not handle.get_facecolors().any():
    handle.set_facecolor(handle.get_edgecolors())

legend = g.axes[0].legend(fancybox=None)

sns.plt.show()
```

The important part is the manipulation of the `handle` objects in `legend` at the end (in the for loop).

This will generate:

[image]

Compared to the original (without the for loop):

[image]

**EDIT:** Now less hacky thanks to suggestions from comments!

Comment: When there is no data, no circle is drawn. I think everyone here would benefit from a [mcve] in the answer, even if the question refuses to provide one.

Comment: You should not access private attributes through `__dict__`. Matplotlib has public methods for getting access to all of these objects, e.g. `ax.get_legend_handles_labels()`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest it's trivially easy to make your own two-point dataframe to test w/.  look in the answer history if you want to see the one i used.  (i took it out because IMO it obfuscated the answer without adding much value, but agree w/ you in general.)

Comment: @mwaskom agreed in general, and nice find!  didn't work tho.  `for handle in g.axes[0].get_legend_handles_labels()[0]`.  maybe it's returning copies?

Comment: Mmm yes it's a bit more complicated, the handles it returns are actually the objects in the axes not in the legend. You'll need to change those and then call `legend` after doing so.

Comment: If it is trivial to provide a [mcve], I don't see the problem of providing that dataframe.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest i don't feel strongly about it.  re-instated DF per your suggestion.